# Question about reflexive pronouns in English

Tags: reflexive-pronouns

**Flesh and sinew mended itself together seamlessly beneath the lantern-like glow of her hand.**

**Flesh and sinew mended themselves together seamlessly beneath the lantern-like glow of her hand.**

---

To my eyes the first sentence seems correct and the second one wrong, but to my brain it's the other way around. "Flesh and sinew" seems like it should be plural, but somehow I intuitively consider it singular. I have come across the same phenomenon recently, written by people who are native English speakers.

Comment: The second reads a bit as though when the mending was done there would be some mended flesh and some mended sinew, rather than a flesh-sinew combination that had been mended together. Is one of those interpretations better than the other? I guess we’d have to ask the author for the intention.

Comment: Flesh and muscle could not mend if they were already one. And *mend itself together* has at least one extra word.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, probably right. My first reading was that a flesh-sinew combination had been rent and that there was a lot of damage, not just separation of intact flesh from intact sinew. But without context, who knows?

Answer (score 3):

You can go both ways. You can view "flesh" and "sinew" as two different substances which mend themselves, and as a result join together. This gives plural agreement, "themselves"

Or you can treat "flesh and sinew" as a single substance, and this allows the use of singular agreement, "itself".

In this case, I prefer the former, as it seems that these are two substances that are being brought together, so I'd use plural agreement.